# Stochastic domination

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose we have two probability measures on a space $X$, $\mu$ and $\nu$, such that $\nu$ stochastically dominates $\mu$, i.e.there exist a coupling of $\mu$ and $\nu$ on the product space $X \times X$, call it $\xi$, such that $\xi$'s respective marginals are $\mu$ and $\nu$ and $\xi[(x_1,x_2) : x_1 \leq x_2] = 1$.

My question is :
is it true that the product measure $\bigotimes_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\nu_k$ on $\prod_{k \in \mathbb{N}}X$ with marginals $\nu_k \sim \nu$ will stochastically dominate  $\bigotimes_{k \in \mathbb{N}}\mu_k$ on $\prod_{k \in \mathbb{N}}X$ given that $\nu_k$ dominates $\mu_k$ on $X$ for every $k$ ?

Comment: I assume that you put the lexicographic order on $\prod_{k \in \mathbb{N}} X$?

Comment: @D.Thomine Yes. Take for example $X = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d}$; then, the product is $Y =  \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{Z}^d \times \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: OK. A  product of couplings is in particular a coupling of products, so you get a coupling $\bigotimes \xi_k$ between $\bigotimes \nu_k$ and $\bigotimes \mu_k$ which should work. Am I wrong?

Comment: @D.Thomine I guess so... but even a product of just two measures confuses me, everything just somehow gets intertwined. If I could prove that $\mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$ is dominated by $\nu_1 \otimes \nu_2$, maybe I'd work out the infinite case, too.

Comment: How would you prove that $\bigotimes \xi_k$ (or $\xi_1 \times \xi_2$) puts mass $1$ on the diagonal when the latter is not the "product" of the smaller diagonals ? Ex. $(0,0) < (1,1)$, but if you append a coordinate at the beginning to get, say, $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,1)$ , you no longer require both parts to satisfy an inequality.

Comment: Let $((x_k),(y_k))$ with distribution given by $\bigotimes \xi_k$. Then $x_1 \leq y_1$ almost surely (because of the choice of $\xi_1$). If $x_1 < y_1$, we're finished. Otherwise, look at $x_2$ and $y_2$.